# How to launch phonon-kde?

Tags: mint, phonon

I removed `pulseaudio` and reloaded `ALSA`, all of a sudden a Phonon GUI showed up where I could change the more preferred audio device.

But I cant launch it (or I don't know the command) in the terminal?

(It was a KDE application, don't know why.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed `kmix`, via kmix I could click on manage audio devices and it showed up.